# aspnet_regiis.exe Output Results

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have an encrypted password in a connection string, contained in a `web.config` file. I do not know what the password is, and thus cannot connect to my database.

I ran `aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf` against the `web.config` and received the following:

```
Decrypting configuration section...
Succeeded!
```

I guess I had assumed that the password would be displayed on the screen, or something close to that? Then I thought the program might create a log file with the information in it? Couldn't find one.

I know I am missing something fundamental, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `decrpty` the `encrypted` password. 
The whole point of `encrypting` the password is so that no one is able to `decrpty` and find what the *password* is unless you know the **key**.

When you *encrypt* the connection string, the `key` is automatically created and stored in the machine where the *encryption* was done.

So, if you copy the *web.config* file to some other machine and do the decryption using:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe –pdf “connectionStrings” YourPathToWebConfigFile
```

This won't work.

And to answer your question, if the *encryption* and *decryption* was done on the same machine, then your `web config` file will change automatically with the *plain text* (*decrypted data)* for *connection string* , not that the password would be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command

```
aspnet_regiis.exe –pdf “connectionStrings” C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication
```

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication needs to be the path where your web.config file is. Once you finish executing above command check your web.config file. If it worked OK you will have decrepted connection string section.